# Mutate multiple columns in R based on conditions

Tags: r

this is probably something stupid I'm doing but I'm trying to join the values of some columns together based on whether they contain a value or not, and then create two new columns called start.week and end.week.

My start.week is "Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday". 
The end.week is "Thursday and Friday".

```
 Name        Monday Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday
 John        Red            Pink        
 Francis     Blue   Gray                 Black  
 Bill        Green          Orange       Purple 
 Bob         Yellow                      Lilac      Magenta
```

I can add the two columns together for Thursday and Friday using:

```
start.week = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")
end.week = c("Thursday", "Friday")

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df = mutate(df, end.week = ifelse(Friday != "", paste0(Thursday, " + ", Friday), Thursday))
```

Back I can't work out how to to this for start.week

Can anyone please give me a hint?  I'd be forever grateful.

Original data:

```
df = structure(list(Name = c("John", "Francis", "Bill", "Bob"), Monday = 
c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"), Tuesday = c("", "Gray", "", ""), 
Wednesday = c("Pink", "", "Orange", ""), Thursday = c("", 
"Black", "Purple", "Lilac"), Friday = c("", "", "", "Magenta"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Expected Output:

```
 df = structure(list(Name = c("John", "Francis", "Bill", "Bob"), Monday = 
 c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"), Tuesday = c("", "Gray", "", ""), 
Wednesday = c("Pink", "", "Orange", ""), Thursday = c("", 
"Black", "Purple", "Lilac"), Friday = c("", "", "", "Magenta"
), start.week = c("Red + Pink", "Black", "Green + Orange", 
"Yellow"), end.week = c("", "", "Purple", "Lilac + Magenta"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I suspect Francis' `start.week` should instead be `"Blue + Gray"`, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -Name) %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(
        start.week = paste(val[key %in% start.week & val != ""], collapse = " + "),
        end.week = paste(val[key %in% end.week & val != ""], collapse = " + ")) %>%
    spread(key, val)
## A tibble: 4 x 8
## Groups:   Name [4]
#  Name    start.week     end.week      Friday Monday Thursday Tuesday Wednesday
#  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>         <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
#1 Bill    Green + Orange Purple        ""     Green  Purple   ""      Orange
#2 Bob     Yellow         Lilac + Mage… Magen… Yellow Lilac    ""      ""
#3 Francis Blue + Gray    Black         ""     Blue   Black    Gray    ""
#4 John    Red + Pink     ""            ""     Red    ""       ""      Pink
```

The idea is to convert data from wide to long, add the new columns `start.week` and `end.week` and then convert data back to wide.

Or we can use `purrr::imap_dfc` to somewhat automate generating the new columns; to do so, we need to store the new columns in a named `list`.

```
lst <- list(start.week = start.week, end.week = end.week)
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -Name) %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(
        tmp = list(imap_dfc(lst, ~paste(val[key %in% .x & val != ""], collapse = "+")))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    spread(key, val)
```

Please note that I think there is a mistake in your expected output; `start.week` for `Francis` should be `Blue + Gray` and not `Black`.

Comment: Thanks Maurits - that's brilliant!

Comment: You're very welcome @HarpoonHarry. Glad it was helpful.